# Simple .htaccess causing me serious headache

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been killing google and apache docs in the previous hours. I just simply can not make it work.

I have a site, with 2 folders, example.com/apple and example.com/banana. My aim is when I open example.com/banana to show /apple folder's content. So the content is coming from different folder, than the URL would suggest.

Codes I tried:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^banana/(.*)$ /apple/$1 [L]
```

Other ...

```
RewriteRule ^banana/?$    http://www.example.com/apple/    [R,NC,L]
```

And am simply unable to figure out ... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be just a uppercase problem. Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^banana/(.*)$ /apple/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Finally I found the problem. There was an other htaccess in the subfolder overriding my command.